# Explode struct column which isn't array in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got a struct column (from json) with this schema:

```
struct_col_name
 |    |-- 2053771759: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2053771760: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2053771761: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
```

Since all of the inner strcuts have the same fields, I want to convert the schema to something like this, and add the `id` (`2053771759` for example) as a field for each element.

By doing it I'll be able to explode the column into rows.

```
struct_col_name
 |    |-- element: struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Any idea how can I do it? Or explode the column by any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the list of `IDs` by using the schema of `df.select("struct_col_name.*")` dataframe. Then, you can loop over that list to update each
struct by adding the `id` field to the existing fields and create an array of struct column. Finally, explode the array column to get one struct by row.

Something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

inner_fields = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
ids = df.select("struct_col_name.*").columns

df = df.select(
    F.explode(F.array(*[
        F.struct(*[
            F.col(f"struct_col_name.{i}.{c}") for c in inner_fields
        ], F.lit(i).alias(i))
        for i in ids
    ])).alias("struct_col_name")
)
```